# Add child elements to XML

Tags: c#, xml, foreach, webmethod, xelement

Can somebody put me in right direction?

What I want to do is get output from WebMethod:

I get the values from a database;

```
1694.152344;1694.092285;1693.972168;1693.852051
2013-07-10 20:00:00;2013-07-10 19:00:00;2013-07-10 18:00:00;2013-07-10 17:00:00
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FieldsRoot xmlns="http://appserver.weevio.se/schema/SDKr1/Fields.xsd">
<Fields ok="true" nodeId="TEST_1.HW">
    <Numeric value="1694.152344" datum="2013-07-10 20:00:00" status="16" />
    <Numeric value="1694.092285" datum="2013-07-10 19:00:00" status="16" />
    <Numeric value="1693.972168" datum="2013-07-10 18:00:00" status="16" />
    <Numeric value="1693.852051" datum="2013-07-10 17:00:00" status="16" />
</Fields>
</FieldsRoot>
```

My code is look likes:

```
[WebMethod]
public XElement Sum2()
{

    XNamespace defaultNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://appserver.weevio.se/schema/SDKr1/Fields.xsd");
    XElement test = new XElement(new XElement(defaultNamespace + "FieldsRoot"));

    string value = "1694.152344;1694.092285;1693.972168;1693.852051";
    string datum = "2013-07-10 20:00:00;2013-07-10 19:00:00;2013-07-10 18:00:00;2013-07-10 17:00:00";

    string[] valueA = value.Split(';');
    string[] datumA = datum.Split(';');

    int d = 0;
    foreach (var customer in valueA)
    {
        XElement xElement = new XElement(defaultNamespace + "Numeric",
                new XAttribute("value", valueA[d]),
                new XAttribute("datum", datumA[d]),
                new XAttribute("status", 16)
        );
        test.Add(new XElement(defaultNamespace + "Fields", new XAttribute("ok", "true"), new XAttribute("nodeId", "TEST.HW"), xElement));
        d = d + 1;
    }
    return test;
}
```

What I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FieldsRoot xmlns="http://appserver.weevio.se/schema/SDKr1/Fields.xsd">
  <Fields ok="true" nodeId="TEST.HW">
    <Numeric value="1694.152344" datum="2013-07-10 20:00:00" status="16" />
  </Fields>
  <Fields ok="true" nodeId="TEST.HW">
    <Numeric value="1694.092285" datum="2013-07-10 19:00:00" status="16" />
  </Fields>
  <Fields ok="true" nodeId="TEST.HW">
    <Numeric value="1693.972168" datum="2013-07-10 18:00:00" status="16" />
  </Fields>
  <Fields ok="true" nodeId="TEST.HW">
    <Numeric value="1693.852051" datum="2013-07-10 17:00:00" status="16" />
  </Fields>
</FieldsRoot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're adding the fields element every time.  This isn't an XML issue, but a logic issue.  Your problem is that you're adding hte "Fields" element inside the for loop.  build all of your elements and then add them all to a single "Fields" element.  Or, build the fields element first and then add the sub-elements to it.  Here's a sample console app showing the difference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Sum2().ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Sum2Working().ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static XElement Sum2()
        {

            XNamespace defaultNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://appserver.weevio.se/schema/SDKr1/Fields.xsd");
            XElement test = new XElement(new XElement(defaultNamespace + "FieldsRoot"));

            string value = "1694.152344;1694.092285;1693.972168;1693.852051";
            string datum = "2013-07-10 20:00:00;2013-07-10 19:00:00;2013-07-10 18:00:00;2013-07-10 17:00:00";

            string[] valueA = value.Split(';');
            string[] datumA = datum.Split(';');

            int d = 0;
            foreach (var customer in valueA)
            {
                XElement xElement = new XElement(defaultNamespace + "Numeric",
                        new XAttribute("value", valueA[d]),
                        new XAttribute("datum", datumA[d]),
                        new XAttribute("status", 16)
                );
                test.Add(new XElement(defaultNamespace + "Fields", new XAttribute("ok", "true"), new XAttribute("nodeId", "TEST.HW"), xElement));
                d = d + 1;
            }
            return test;
        }

        public static XElement Sum2Working()
        {

            XNamespace defaultNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://appserver.weevio.se/schema/SDKr1/Fields.xsd");
            XElement test = new XElement(new XElement(defaultNamespace + "FieldsRoot"));

            string value = "1694.152344;1694.092285;1693.972168;1693.852051";
            string datum = "2013-07-10 20:00:00;2013-07-10 19:00:00;2013-07-10 18:00:00;2013-07-10 17:00:00";

            string[] valueA = value.Split(';');
            string[] datumA = datum.Split(';');

            int d = 0;

            var fields = new List<XElement>();

            foreach (var customer in valueA)
            {
                XElement xElement = new XElement(defaultNamespace + "Numeric",
                        new XAttribute("value", valueA[d]),
                        new XAttribute("datum", datumA[d]),
                        new XAttribute("status", 16)
                );
                fields.Add(xElement);
                d = d + 1;
            }

            test.Add(new XElement(defaultNamespace + "Fields", new XAttribute("ok", "true"), new XAttribute("nodeId", "TEST.HW"), fields));

            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, Sum2Working() adds the elements to a list and then adds the list to the larger element.

Comment: I understand what you mean.
How do I do that? I am totally a novice when it comes to C # and object-oriented languages

Comment: When I create a "Fields" element (before the loop) and in loop  I only add a "Nuberic" element like you did, it never close a "Fields" tag

Comment: <Fields ok="true" nodeId="TEST.HW">

Comment: Thank you deltree! That was exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the

```
test.Add(new XElement(defaultNamespace + "Fields", new XAttribute("ok", "true"), new XAttribute("nodeId", "TEST.HW"), xElement));
```

Outside the foreach loop in order to achieve that.

Try

```
[WebMethod]
public XElement Sum2()
{
XNamespace defaultNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://appserver.weevio.se/schema/SDKr1/Fields.xsd");
XElement test = new XElement(new XElement(defaultNamespace + "FieldsRoot"));

string value = "1694.152344;1694.092285;1693.972168;1693.852051";
string datum = "2013-07-10 20:00:00;2013-07-10 19:00:00;2013-07-10 18:00:00;2013-07-10 17:00:00";

string[] valueA = value.Split(';');
string[] datumA = datum.Split(';');

int d = 0;

Xelement numericElement = new Xelement(); 
foreach (var customer in valueA)
{
    XElement xElement = new XElement(defaultNamespace + "Numeric",
            new XAttribute("value", valueA[d]),
            new XAttribute("datum", datumA[d]),
            new XAttribute("status", 16)
    );
    numericElement.Add(xElement);
    d = d + 1;
}
test.Add(new XElement(defaultNamespace + "Fields", new XAttribute("ok", "true"), new XAttribute("nodeId", "TEST.HW"), numericElement));
return test;
```

}

Comment: IF I do that, then I get an error:
"The name xElement are not in the current context"